# Message in flight for SQS Lambda Trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have SQS which triggers lambda.

When i put message in SQS Queue it shows message in flight and my lambda is not able to process message.

My Lambda has below permissions

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sqs:DeleteMessage",
                "sqs:GetQueueUrl",
                "sqs:ListDeadLetterSourceQueues",
                "sqs:DeleteMessageBatch",
                "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
                "sqs:GetQueueAttributes",
                "sqs:ListQueueTags"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

ALso it has below permissions

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:5722*****:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:5722****:log-group:/aws/lambda/815223_Test:*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

When i attach "Administator access" permission permission it works and lambda gets triggered.
I am not sure which permission i am missging here.My SQS queue is un-encrypted.

Comment: is there anything more than "console.log" your lambda function doing ?

Comment: @Oxi No It only reads message from  SQS

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the CloudTrail to identify the root cause for the API failure. Also check the Queue policy being used for your SQS.

You only need the below permissions for a default SQS and Lambda combination.

```
- "SQS:SendMessage"
- "SQS:ReceiveMessage"
- "SQS:DeleteMessage"
- "SQS:GetQueueAttributes"
```

Below is a sample CloudFormation template for your reference.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: >
  Creates the SQS and Lambda pattern
Resources:
  # SQS queue and queue policy
  FileProcessingEventsQueue:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      QueueName: "FileProcessingEventsQueue"
      VisibilityTimeout: 60
  FileProcessingEventsQueuePolicy:
    Type: AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy
    Properties:
      Queues:
        - !Ref FileProcessingEventsQueue
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action:
              - "SQS:*"
            Effect: "Allow"
            Resource: !GetAtt FileProcessingEventsQueue.Arn
            Principal:
              AWS: "*"
            Condition:
              StringEquals:
                aws:SourceAccount: !Sub "${AWS::AccountId}"
  # Lambda function and role for handling the SQS events
  LambdaExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action: "sts:AssumeRole"
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: InlinePolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              - Action:
                  - "SQS:SendMessage"
                  - "SQS:ReceiveMessage"
                  - "SQS:DeleteMessage"
                  - "SQS:GetQueueAttributes"
                Effect: Allow
                Resource: "*"
  LambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Description: "Lambda for the event processing"
      Runtime: "python3.7"
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn
      Handler: index.handler
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 60
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          import json
          import logging

          # Configure logging

          LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)
          LOGGER.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

          def handler(event, context):
              LOGGER.debug(json.dumps(event, indent=4, default=str))
              data = {'status': 'event printed'}
              return data
  SQSAndLambdaMapping:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping
    Properties:
      EventSourceArn: !GetAtt FileProcessingEventsQueue.Arn
      FunctionName: !GetAtt LambdaFunction.Arn
Outputs:
  SQSQueue:
    Description: File processing queue
    Value: !Ref FileProcessingEventsQueue
```

Comment: I don't think that the Lambda function requires any Amazon SQS permissions, since the Lambda service is responsible for retrieving the message from the queue, providing it to the function via the `event` field, then deleting the message when complete.

Comment: You are right the lambda does not have to call SQS but the lambda role is used to create the event source mapping with the SQS, followed by the subsequent message receive and deletion from the queue. The permission is solely for that. The message itself is part of the incoming event payload.

Comment: You will notice the `ApproximateReceiveCount` go up and same message received repeatedly in the CloudWatch, if the `DeleteMessage` permission is not provided.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the clarification! I hadn't realised that SQS permissions were need to setup the trigger itself ("Event Source Mapping"). Most interesting! I agree that CloudTrail should provide the clues for what commands are failing due to insufficient permissions.